# Django Tastypie, run an action

Tags: django, api, orm, django-models, tastypie

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. I am currently trying to build an API with Django and Tastypie.

I would like to have a http request lookup a model via a primary key then run a model method/action.

I can't seem to identify and matching docs or methods to achieve what seems like a simple action..

Thanks for any pointers,

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe TastyPie is used to run model methods. It wraps the model up as a Resource and exposes a set of methods, mainly get,post,put. Take a look at [Django TastyPie QuickStart](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#quick-start)

The methods you can expose are those of a REST api and not custom methods.

Comment: I thinks he means to add them as subresources, as DjangoREST does.